# Should the "Title:" label on the question entry form be changed to "Question:"?

Tags: feature-request

RE: [Should every question's title be edited into a short question?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/553/should-every-questions-title-be-edited-into-a-short-question/560#comment616_560)

In my opinion, this would re-enforce the idea the question titles should be QUESTIONS.

Comment: The same question was [asked on meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82064/is-it-possible-to-rename-the-title-field-to-question-on-the-ask-question-f), and Jeff Atwood responded.